# Extracting grouped data in R

Tags: r, sample-data

This may be a basic question, but I want to calculate the average bond wealth for seniors aged 65-74, and only for those with bonds (>0) and eliminate no replies (which is signaled by the 9999...).

```
mean(Bonds[Age>64 & Age<75 & Bonds>0 & Bonds<999999999999])
```

I'm getting an error message:
longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that's not a warning? There's a big difference, and R will explicitly say whether its a warning or an error.

Comment: What is length(Age) and length(Bonds), or better yet just dput them?

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from the question how the data is shaped; I assume `Bonds` is a `data.frame` with two columns `Bonds` and `Age`. Then

```
idx <- Bonds$Age>64 & Bonds$Age<75 & Bonds$Bonds>0 & Bonds$Bonds<999999999999
```

indicates which rows fullfill the conditions and

```
mean(Bonds[idx, "Bonds"])
```

returns the mean of the column `Bonds`.

Comment: Thank you very much - your replies made me think that my approach was ok, and the suggestions helped me figure out the problem.  I was using two large datasets, whose variable names should have been the same (same survey from two different years), but the age variable name was changed by a letter, so I was grabbing one variable from one year, and the other from the other year - hence the warning (thank you, for the distinction, joran).  The length suggestion showed me the problem, Ari. Thank you, Karsten, for showing me a new way to do it.